# Location by click to autocomplete fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Is there any possibility that in autocomplete fragment will show my location when I click on the map?

What I mean is, when somebody wants to search for a place via the map rather than by location address, i.e. by looking on the map for the place and pressing/touching/clicking on a street, then that place will be marked and I want to get the street name sent to my fragment.

This is my current code - I hope that you understand my problem:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);



    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    SharedPreferences locationsp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String sp = locationsp.getString("Location2","No location found");
    //search.setText(sp);
    if(!sp.equals("No location found")){
        autocompleteFragment.setText(sp);
        tmp=sp;
    }


    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            onSearch(place);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }


        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    try {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                        .setFilter(typeFilter)
                        .build(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }




    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    setUpMap();

    locationt = findViewById(R.id.mapViewfrag);
    savelocation = findViewById(R.id.savelocation);
    //search = findViewById(R.id.GameLocation);

    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("You are here");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

            PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

            map.clear();
            Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude), 15));
            latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            longtitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
            try {
                Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longtitude, 1);
                System.out.println(addresses);


                if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    locationt.setText("Waiting for Location");
                } else {
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {                          locationt.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                        //autocompleteFragment.getText(); <<<Thats what i try but it makes me error
                       locationname=locationt.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: What is issue? Where you are stuck?

Comment: The problem is when i get addresses and then wanna them give to my Fragment, dont know how to do this, didnt found any options, so im asking is there any posibilitis to get addres and save it or i need to make new own thing looks like this fragment

Comment: You can create interface for this.

Comment: Could you show me how ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/3364266 check this

Comment: So, I can now send addresses to callback, hmmm i need to check out this, dont know that would solve my solution, will try it and tell you results after it :)

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Comment: I was sick for a week, today im loking at this and have no clue how it works for my problem