# No methods in AsyncTask is ever called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an implementation of AsyncTask in my application, but I have a problem.

Here is my implementation of AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTaskPost extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

    private View mView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressbar;
    private Context mContext;

    public AsyncTaskPost(View view, Context context){
        mView = view;
        mProgressbar = (ProgressBar)mView.findViewById(R.id.progressPostUser);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
public void onSaveClicked(User user) {
    try {
        String nameTest = user.get_name();
        String surnameTest = user.get_surname();

        new AsyncTaskPost(mView, mContext).execute(new URL("www.blahblah.com"));
        //new AsyncTaskPost(mView, mContext).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new URL("www.blahblah.com"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

When I debug the app, I can step into the constructor, but after that, none of the `onPreStart`, 'doInBackground' is called?

Why is this happening?

Comment: `new AsyncTaskPost(mView, mContext).execute(new URL("www.blahblah.com"));`. It is not started/executed in that way. Change to `new AsyncTaskPost(mView, mContext).execute(new URL("www.blahblah.com")).execute();`

Comment: Can you step into an `execute` method with debugger? what happens there?

Comment: I would suggest using threads instead of asynctask

Comment: @greenapps your comment is wrong, you don't need to call execute twice, it is the same method with or without arguments

Comment: Sorry. Stupid mistake of me. Now i see it. A shame ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing runs because your code causes a `MalformedURLException`

as per importing your code into Android Studio I got:

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: www.blahblah.com
```

If you clean this up it will work just fine, However you have a few significant problems with your design.

1. An AsyncTask does not and should not use `Context` if it can be avoided, especially given that AS will tell you it is creating a leak.

Use Callbacks (i.e interface with some functions like showToast(), or displayProgress(Integer value)) to avoid having to do things such as show a `Toast`... which here, you have not called show() on your `Toast` anyways.

2. In addition to not passing `Context` you should definitely not pass your `View` into your `AsyncTask` because what happens when your `View` is gone but `AsyncTask` calls `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)`.... the app will crash. (same can be said if Context is no longer valid i.e null)

   see using [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) if you can't remove the dependencies.

Make these changes and you will be all set.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers.  How am I supposed to access, for instance, my ProgressBar without passing the View to AsyncTask, as used in Android's examples?  If I pass in a valid URL, I can see the Progressbar.

Comment: @android_monstertjie you can use Intent and BroadcastReceivers or create an interface as per my comment above and pass along the reference to that interface into the AsyncTask and implement the interface in the Activity or Fragment hosting the View.

Comment: I see what yo mean, with the following example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android

Thanks