# set text for a TextView when http connection timeout

Tags: java, android

I need to set text for a `TextView` when http connection timeout as an error message
I need this to be done on `MainActivity.java` but request is made from `QueryUtils.java`
I tried to do that using findViewByid but I got an error because of using static method to watch errors
here is my QueryUtils,java

```
package com.example.android.mynewsx2;


    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    /**
     * Created by Person on 11/08/2018.
     */

    public class QueryUtils {

        public boolean connTimeout = false;
        static String createStringUrl() {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .encodedAuthority("content.guardianapis.com")
                    .appendPath("search")
                    .appendQueryParameter("order-by", "newest")
                    .appendQueryParameter("show-references", "author")
                    .appendQueryParameter("show-tags", "contributor")
                    .appendQueryParameter("page-size", "175")
                    .appendQueryParameter("q", "")
                    .appendQueryParameter("api-key", "c15d8295-7691-4172-a257-a7d065668eb4");
            String url = builder.build().toString();
            return url;
        }

        static URL createUrl() {
            String stringUrl = createStringUrl();
            try {
                return new URL(stringUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("Queryutils", "Error creating URL: ", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static String formatDate(String rawDate) {
            String jsonDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
            SimpleDateFormat jsonFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(jsonDatePattern, Locale.US);
            try {
                Date parsedJsonDate = jsonFormatter.parse(rawDate);
                String finalDatePattern = "MMM d, yyy";
                SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(finalDatePattern, Locale.US);
                return finalDateFormatter.format(parsedJsonDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("QueryUtils", "Error parsing JSON date: ", e);
                return "";
            }
        }

        static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = "";

            if (url == null){
                return jsonResponse;
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.connect();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
                } else {
                    Log.e("mainActivity", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Queryutils", "Error making HTTP request: ", e);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        static List<News> parseJson(String response) {
            ArrayList<News> listOfNews = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject jsonResults = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONArray resultsArray = jsonResults.getJSONArray("results");

                for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject oneResult = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String webTitle = oneResult.getString("webTitle");
                    String url = oneResult.getString("webUrl");
                    String date = oneResult.getString("webPublicationDate");
                    date = formatDate(date);
                    String section = oneResult.getString("sectionName");
                    JSONArray tagsArray = oneResult.getJSONArray("tags");
                    String author = "";

                    if (tagsArray.length() == 0) {
                        author = null;
                    } else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < tagsArray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject firstObject = tagsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            author += firstObject.getString("webTitle") + ". ";
                        }
                    }
                    listOfNews.add(new News(webTitle, author, url, date, section));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Queryutils", "Error parsing JSON response", e);
            }
            return listOfNews;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use interface..

Comment: Check out this interface : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the callback (interfaces).

The following code snippet is what you have to do :

```
static String makeHttpRequest(URL url, OnTimeOutListener listener) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.connect();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {

            //Call this when time out happens
            listener.onTimeOut();
            Log.e("mainActivity", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Queryutils", "Error making HTTP request: ", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}

interface OnTimeOutListener {
    void onTimeOut();
}
```

In your MainActivity you have to call makeHttpRequest that way

```
QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(url, new OnTimeOutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeOut() {
          //Handle your call timeout.
        }
    });
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `interface`.

1) Create a `interface` in your `QueryUtils` class.

2) Implements this `interface` in your activity.

3) Pass reference of your interface to  `QueryUtils` class.

4). call `interface` method whenever timeout.

Please see below code

`QueryUtils` class

```
public class QueryUtils {

public interface OnConnectionTimeOut {
    void onTimeOut();
}

public static OnConnectionTimeOut objTimeOutListener;

public void setTimeOutListener(OnConnectionTimeOut listener) {
    objTimeOutListener = listener;
}

public boolean connTimeout = false;

public static String createStringUrl() {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("http")
            .encodedAuthority("content.guardianapis.com")
            .appendPath("search")
            .appendQueryParameter("order-by", "newest")
            .appendQueryParameter("show-references", "author")
            .appendQueryParameter("show-tags", "contributor")
            .appendQueryParameter("page-size", "175")
            .appendQueryParameter("q", "")
            .appendQueryParameter("api-key", "c15d8295-7691-4172-a257-a7d065668eb4");
    String url = builder.build().toString();
    return url;
}

static URL createUrl() {
    String stringUrl = createStringUrl();
    try {
        return new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Queryutils", "Error creating URL: ", e);
        return null;
    }
}

private static String formatDate(String rawDate) {
    String jsonDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    SimpleDateFormat jsonFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(jsonDatePattern, Locale.US);
    try {
        Date parsedJsonDate = jsonFormatter.parse(rawDate);
        String finalDatePattern = "MMM d, yyy";
        SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(finalDatePattern, Locale.US);
        return finalDateFormatter.format(parsedJsonDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Error parsing JSON date: ", e);
        return "";
    }
}

static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.connect();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            objTimeOutListener.onTimeOut();
            Log.e("mainActivity", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        objTimeOutListener.onTimeOut();
        Log.e("Queryutils", "Error making HTTP request: ", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}

private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            output.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

static List<News> parseJson(String response) {
    ArrayList<News> listOfNews = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject jsonResults = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray resultsArray = jsonResults.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject oneResult = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String webTitle = oneResult.getString("webTitle");
            String url = oneResult.getString("webUrl");
            String date = oneResult.getString("webPublicationDate");
            date = formatDate(date);
            String section = oneResult.getString("sectionName");
            JSONArray tagsArray = oneResult.getJSONArray("tags");
            String author = "";

            if (tagsArray.length() == 0) {
                author = null;
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < tagsArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject firstObject = tagsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    author += firstObject.getString("webTitle") + ". ";
                }
            }
            listOfNews.add(new News(webTitle, author, url, date, section));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Queryutils", "Error parsing JSON response", e);
    }
    return listOfNews;
}
```

}

`Activity` class code

```
public class DataActivity extends Activity implements QueryUtils.OnConnectionTimeOut {


    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        super.setContentView(view);
        QueryUtils obj = new QueryUtils();
        obj.setTimeOutListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeOut() {

        Log.e("This method will be called on timeout", "");
      //Set text here
    }
}
```