# How to display bluetooth message in text view (Message is recieved in a seperate class and not in main activity)

Tags: android

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;


    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if (socket != null) {
                connected(socket, mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }

            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     * Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Connecting Bluetooth"
                , "Please Wait...", true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     * receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     **/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;


            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }


}
```

in this code the incoming message in the input stream is being displayed in Log the whole code is in a class and not an activity. What should i do to display the incoming message in activity main. I'm new to android please help me solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces to send data to Activity from your class, you can find the example of how to use interfaces here:
[How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

you have to create the interface like this in your class

```
public interface BluetoothMessageListener {
        void onMessageReceived(String message);
    }
```

implement this interface in your activity where you want to display the message and passed that interface reference to your class.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: null pointer exception is crashing the app could u please help

Comment: can you share the crash log

Answer (score 0):

1) Create Handler in BluetoothConnectionService class

```
private final Handler mHandler;
```

2)Add in constractor

```
 public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context,Handler handler) {
    mContext = context;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mHandler = handler;
    start();
}
```

3)Add this to ConnectedThread(where you show that log)

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
mHandler.obtainMessage(1000, incomingMessage , -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

4) Now in MainActiviy create Handler

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler mhandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case 1000:
                String message = (String) msg.obj;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

5) Create your Service in onCreate() like this

```
mService = new BluetoothConnectionService(MainActivity.this,mhandler);
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: mHandler.obtainMessage(1000, incomingMessage , -1, buffer).sendToTarget();   the incomingmessage is being encapsulated in integer.parseint and the app is crashing before toast is displayed.  Can u please help with this

Comment: null pointer exception is crashing the app could u please help

Comment: @ManuPrasad you forget number 2 or number 5