# Update recyclerview item on resume

Tags: android

I have firstactivity that has recycler view and recyclerview item contains imageview and one button of favourite.and on click on button i have to call api of mark and unmark favourite.and on click on image i am opening different activity,and this second activity also has option to mark and unmark favourite.I am able to do this all.but my question is if i am calling mark fvrt from second activity,it should be updated on first activity.
I am managing mark and unmark from boolean value.but onResume of first activity i need to update that paricular item.Calling api is not solution of this.So what should i do.

Comment: going to have to show a bit of code so we can see what you're actually trying to do I feel like i know whats wrong but cant tell for sure if I cant see anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom listener to detect which item changed and notify this item, check this link please to create custom listener [How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

**Or**

You can call the Api in `onResume()`

1. Call api in `onResume()`
2. Set `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);` (Optional)
3. Clear RecyclerView items
4. Set new data