# Need to update image from drawable in cardview if a get volley request is true(200 ok)

Tags: java, android, android-volley, cardview

I have an app which checks if website is working by pinging website via volley 
If request is made I can log whether request is successful or not 
I am facing trouble in showing it in cardview
I have a onBindViewHolder which populates all elements in cardview 
There is a 'ischeck' function inside onBindViewHolder which checks if request is made 
But since I am using volley I can't return a value from onResponse

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                         Log.d("istrue","yes");
                        Toast.makeText(context1, "Success: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

So how do I populate cardview from onResponse function ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Volley requests are made asynchronously (in a background thread), you cannot simply return the result. What you need is a listener.

1. Declare an `interface` as a listener.
2. Implement it in your `Activity`/ `Fragment`.
3. Pass the `interface` reference to the class that's making Volley
   request.
4. From `onResponse`, call the listener callback method with the response
   value.
5. Now you got the response to your `Activity`/ `Fragment`, where you can update your `RecyclerView`.

For an example code, [check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/4586742)

Answer (score 0):

you need an interface to get callback from web service:

```
public interface ServerCallback {
    void onSuccess(String s);
    void onError(Exception e);
}
```

then after that use interface in Web Service class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class WebService {

    private static WebService ourInstance;

    public static WebService getInstance() {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            ourInstance = new WebService();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public void sample(Context context, ServerCallback serverCallback) {
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "Your URL", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                serverCallback.onSuccess(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                serverCallback.onError(error);
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

finally get callback and do whatever you want from your class using this code:

```
    WebService.getInstance().sample(this, new ServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            // do every thing you want
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            // handle error response
        }
    });
}
```