# Listener for data in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to get a current number of items in **RecyclerView** every time when **notifyDataSetChanged()** method is called? I'd like to use something like LiveData, so i can observe changes in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the size of the list in recyclerView every time you call notifyDataSetChanged() or you can use listeners to get a cleaner code.

Comment: That's what i want - use a listener. But is seems like RecyclerView doen't have any default listeners to observe the number of items.

Comment: No it doesn't have any, but you can add it to your class if you want, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/9426046) if you don't know how to add listeners.

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged() rebinds holders, so you can try to get this data inside of onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: putting it inside `onBindViewHolder` doesn't seem useful - at this point you will already have called notifyDataSetChanged, so you could have checked the size _before_ calling it