# Change view from another thread

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to change a TextView from another thread in another class, but I am not sure how to best solve this.

I am making an instant messaging application and when receiving a message through an input stream I want to change the view which is set in another class.

Should a listener be implemented to eg handle it like this?

1. Client 1 reads a message through `message = inputstream.readObject()` in class A
2. An Observer/Listener function in class B is called through class A and sets a TextView with the `message` value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution - to use custom Listener interface - [How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android/18585247;)

Dont forget, that ui can be changed only from MAIN thread.
If you have access to activity, you can use:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
//change the view
});
```

If you dont:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {/*change*/ });
```